# burning legs fat and avoiding Slouch

Tags: running, long-distance-running, fat, legs

I am 22 , my weight is 77 KG and I am 170 cm Long.

Through the last two years I have been [Running] around 4 days weekly. I lost around 21 KG from 92 to 71 in the last year as I was doing diet. This year I continued the same level of running [ I have improved a lot ], However I gained 6 KG back.

My question now is : How to loose my legs and thighs fat. Although I mainly train them [ while running ] I still can't burn their fat. I was successful in burning belly fat and all my body in general, but I am stuck with the legs and thigh fat

any advice will be really appreciated

Comment: This might be a rookie question but **what makes you believe your thighs/legs are fat?** You should distinguish between fat and muscles; it seems hard to believe that with running, you lost fat everywhere else except for the legs.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD Good question, and I was always asking myself the same question > to answer it : I can grip the fat, measure the leg size and all those signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Mårten said, you either lose fat over your entire body, or nowhere at all. You can't pick and choose where to gain/lose fat.

As for losing then gaining weight, the difference lies in your diet. You mention that you dieted when you lost weight, and after that you started to gain weight again. This should be a telltale sign. And it's a well-established fact in the fitness industry; weight loss and weight gain is done in the kitchen.

Count calories! If you want to lose weight, try hitting 1700 kcal / day, and see what happens over 2-3 weeks. If you lose weight, stick with it. If you remain at the same weight, or gain weight, then try lowering your diet to 1600 kcal / day. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: As I said, I lost a lot of weight and it was not 2-3 weeks, it was almost a full year of running. and was burning around 2800 kcal each week ( as I can see from the running application (runtastic)) just by running.

Comment: @iShaalan - Read my post again. I realize you didn't do it over 2-3 weeks. I used that time interval as an example for my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot burn fat in a specific location, legs do not use only leg fat, and so on. If you want less fat on your legs you will need to reduce fat overall.

Comment: Here is the problem : I lost A LOT of weight (almost 20 KG) and most of it was from my face and upper body, I am not saying I want to determine which part of the body should burn fat faster but I want to know why legs fat does not burn as steady as any other body part

Comment: Genetics. Also it's a matter of perception. Sometimes we lose fat but you don't see it as clearly.